# cakephp phone number validation

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1

i am new to cakephp 2.x so  i dont know how to do this .. i want to login the user from his email address and phone number..what my intention is if the number in database is this "12345" and the user is trying to login through this number "+12345" he can be login into the system.. i have written a code but i dont know how can i use this or to adjust my code within the auth component as the auth component is autometically logging the user ..

here is my controller

```
 public function beforeFilter() {
    parent::beforeFilter();


    $this->Auth->authenticate = array(
        'Authenticate.Cookie' => array(
            'fields' => array(
                'username' => 'email',
                'password' => 'password'
            ),
            'userModel' => 'User',
            'scope' => array('User.active' => 1)
        ),
        'Authenticate.MultiColumn' => array(
            'fields' => array(
                'username' => 'email',
                'password' => 'password'
            ),
            'columns' => array('email', 'mobileNo'),
            'userModel' => 'User',
        )
    );
 }




public function login() {


    if ($this->Auth->login() || $this->Auth->loggedIn()) {
        $this->redirect('/users/dashboard');
    }else{
    $this->layout='logindefault';
    $this->set('title_for_layout', 'Account Login');
    /*$this->Auth->logout();
     $cookie = $this->Cookie->read('Auth.User'); */


    if ($this->request->is('post')) {




        if ($this->Auth->login() || $this->Auth->loggedIn()) {
            if ($this->Session->check('Auth.User')){


            $this->_setCookie($this->Auth->user('idUser'));
            $this->redirect('/users/dashboard');

        } }else {
            $this->Session->setFlash('Incorrect Email/Password Combination');
        }
    }}
}
```

here is the code which i am trying to add ..

```
    $mobileNo='+123456789';
   if (strpos($mobileNo,'+') !== false) {
      $mobileNo=str_replace("+", "",$mobileNo);
   }
```

?>

Answer (score 0):

The docs ( http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation.html#custom-validation-rules ) have examples on custom validation rules.

But your use case is not about validation (for login there is no normal validation, only a "scope" can be applied).
Its about customizing the data that goes into login.
You can either use the login() method to modify incoming data prior to the Auth->login() call or use the new 2.x way of doing it: using custom auth adapters.

```
// in your AppController::beforeFilter() method
$this->Auth->authorize = array('PhoneNumber');
```

and your PhoneNumber adapter should then be called PhoneNumberAuthenticate and be placed in /Controller/Component/Auth.

See https://github.com/ceeram/Authenticate for details on how others adapters work and apply it to your own one.

But since you are also using "email" to login, you might be best of using the replacement option in your login method:

```
public function login() {
    $this->request->data['User']['email'] = $this->_replace($this->request->data['User']['email']);
    if ($this->Auth->login()) {...}
```

with _replace() containing your replacment code.

Comment: i dont know how can i do this ... if you have implemented or working on this functionality before then share the code if you dont mind otherwise its up to do .. as i am stuck here right now

Comment: didnt get you.. who i am replacing ... why should i replace ... what i want to do is.. i want to login the user from email, number and +number..

Comment: exactly - arent you using `str_replace` in your method to "unify" the format? just put that code there (either as own method in controller or model - or inline).

Answer (score 0):

i have done this and it works

i add this line just before the $this->Auth->login()
   $this->request->data['User']['email'] = $mobileNo;

source:[string concatenation when user log in Cakephp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17342847/string-concatenation-when-user-log-in-cakephp)