# string concatenation when user log in Cakephp

Tags: cakephp, authentication, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1

i am working on a cakephp 2.x .. what i want is i want to login the user from email and phone number... and if user during  log in he typed the number with out adding '+' he can be able to log into the system .. so i want to check first if the typed number has "+" or not .. if not concatenate + with the number and then process the query.. i dont know how can i used this in auth component as i auth autometically logging the user ..

example 1234556:
add + then : +1234556

in my **login .ctp** my input box name is **'email'** in which number or email is comming

here is my **Controller**

```
     public function beforeFilter() {
    parent::beforeFilter();


    $this->Auth->authenticate = array(
        'Authenticate.Cookie' => array(
            'fields' => array(
                'username' => 'email',
                'password' => 'password'
            ),
            'userModel' => 'User',
            'scope' => array('User.active' => 1)
        ),
        'Authenticate.MultiColumn' => array(
            'fields' => array(
                'username' => 'email',
                'password' => 'password'
            ),
            'columns' => array('email', 'mobileNo'),
            'userModel' => 'User',
        )
    );
   }
      public function login() {


      $mobileNo=$this->request->data['User']['email'];



    $pos = strpos($mobileNo,'@');
    if($pos){

        echo 'yes';
    }else {

        $mystr=substr($mobileNo,0,1);
        if ($mystr!='+'){
            $mobileNo = '+'.$mobileNo;
        }
    }

  // DONT KNow how can i pass this mobile No

    if ($this->Auth->login() || $this->Auth->loggedIn()) {
        $this->redirect('/users/dashboard');
    }else{
    $this->layout='logindefault';
    $this->set('title_for_layout', 'Account Login');
    /*$this->Auth->logout();
     $cookie = $this->Cookie->read('Auth.User'); */


    if ($this->request->is('post')) {




        if ($this->Auth->login() || $this->Auth->loggedIn()) {
            if ($this->Session->check('Auth.User')){


            $this->_setCookie($this->Auth->user('idUser'));
            $this->redirect('/users/dashboard');

        } }else {
            $this->Session->setFlash('Incorrect Email/Password Combination');//this will redisplay the login page
        }
    }}
}
```

Comment: now kind of a duplicate of your http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17338364/cakephp-phone-number-validation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should update $this->request, so

```
$this->request->data['User']['email'] = $mobileNo; // there $mobileNo is your updated value
```

and you should to it before `$this->Auth->login()`

Comment: well i do mention here in database there is two separate fields mobileNo and email ... but there is only one input field in login.ctp file name email ... so if user typed email my query check email or if he typed number query check the mobileNo field...